# Vehicle Technology Controls

Tags: honda, toyota, hyundai, kia, emissions

Could anyone tell me what "cars Petrol <1,4L Euro-1" means? I really appreciate if anyone can tell me reliable sites to get information about the all the types of vehicle technology controls i.e fuel control, evaporative control, Exhausted control..etc.

Best Regards,

Comment: Regarding your question, could you provide more context?

Comment: I believe what the OP is getting at is that Petrol cars with less than a 1.4L engine can utilize Euro-1 fuels, but really not sure.

Comment: @BobCross how can I know euro standard of types of vehicles ? 1.4L is cylinder?